# Downsampling 4:4:4 YUV video to 4:2:2?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, yuv

I'm attempting to downsample a YUV raw video in FFMPEG from 444 to 422 sampling, but the issue is that the output file remains 444?! Framerate and size is all correct. Here's my most recent code:

```
ffmpeg -s:v 3840x2160 -r 50 -i input.yuv -vf scale=3840:2160 -c:v rawvideo -pixel_format yuv422p10le output.yuv
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing: [`-pixel_format`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) applies the input and [`-pix_fmt`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Video-options) applies the output, but may also be used as shortcut for `-pixel_format`.

Assume pixel format of `input.yuv` is `yuv444p10le`, use the following command:

`ffmpeg -s:v 3840x2160 -pixel_format yuv444p10le -i input.yuv -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p10le output.yuv`

---

Testing:

- Build `input.yuv` with 100 frames 384x216 with `yuv444p10le` pixel format:
  `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=1:duration=100 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p10le input.yuv`
  The file size is 384*216*100*3*2 = 49,766,400 bytes (100 frames, 3 color channels and 2 bytes per component).
- Convert pixel format to `yuv422p10le`:
  `ffmpeg -y -s:v 384x216 -pixel_format yuv444p10le -i input.yuv -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p10le output.yuv`
  The file size is 384*216*100*2*2 = 33,177,600 bytes (100 frames, were Y has 2 bytes per component, and U,V has 2 bytes per 2 components).

For testing, we may play `input.yuv` and `output.yuv` using FFplay:
`ffplay -framerate 1 -video_size 384x216 -pixel_format yuv444p10le -i input.yuv`
`ffplay -framerate 1 -video_size 384x216 -pixel_format yuv422p10le -i output.yuv`

---

Note about `scale` filter:

By default using `scale` filter, gives the same result as without it (FFmpeg uses the  scale filter internally for converting yuv444 to yuv422):

`ffmpeg -y -s:v 384x216 -pixel_format yuv444p10le -i input.yuv -vf scale=dst_format=yuv422p10le -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p10le output2.yuv` gives the same output as before.

But using `scale` filter, we have more control - we may select the interpolation method for example:

`ffmpeg -y -s:v 384x216 -pixel_format yuv444p10le -i input.yuv -vf scale=sws_flags=lanczos:dst_format=yuv422p10le -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p10le output2.yuv`